# Images lost in distribution build for SpriteKit app

Tags: sprite-kit, testflight, sprite-sheet

While running debug and release builds on a device connected to Xcode, I see the images loaded from atlas folders just fine, developing a SpriteKit game.

I set up a Jenkins job to checkout the project from svn repo, build it, and send it off to iTC TestFlight. When I download the app off TestFlight the images are gone, and are replaced by Xes. What could possible cause this?

**Update 1**: Seems like the Jenkins job produces an .ipa where the images are Xes already. I use Shenzhen for building... maybe there is a problem there, or with the checkout...

**Update 2**: I am starting to think Shenzhen is the culprit, or maybe I am... um, using Shenzhen in a bad way. Comparing the appstore IPA from Shenzhen and the adhoc IPA I created manually in Xcode, I noticed that only the adhoc build has the atlases really summed up to singular atlases - the images are just copied one by one (in their folder) to the IPA by the Shenzhen build so there has been no atlas process going on in the build. I might be able to track down the problem with Shenzhen from here... tomorrow. Time to get home.

**Update 3**: On the subway home and I found this which looks very related. Problem looks like an issue with command line builds. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20825149/129202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem stemmed not from any 3rd party tools, but from xcodebuild, or some other command line tool that for some reason does not compile texture atlases.
The best solution seems to be like in the linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20825149/129202

Quoted:

Custom script:

```
${DEVELOPER_TOOLS_DIR}/../usr/bin/TextureAtlas ${INPUT_FILE_PATH} ${DERIVED_FILE_DIR}
```

Output files:

```
${DERIVED_FILE_DIR}/${INPUT_FILE_BASE}.atlasc
```